# How to place a framed full-width text box on the bottom of the last page in two column documents?

Tags: floats, two-column, pandoc

for a publication, I would like to place bibliographic and license information in a full-width framed text box on the bottom of the last page. While this can be achieved on one-column documents with `\vfill` and `\fbox`, I do not know how this can be done in two column documents. How could this be achieved?

Note that my content is a [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) export from markdown and that pandoc typesets images using the figure environment. In order to avoid monkeypatching (if possible at all) pandoc code or the figure environment, I prefer not to use the `multicol` package, which otherwise works perfect.

## Closest Take so Far

MWE for one column-width box:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{MWE}
\author{Test Developer}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\lipsum[2-4]

\begin{figure}
 % placeholder for includegraphics
 \begin{framed}
  \vspace{1em}
 \end{framed}
 \caption{Test Figure}
\end{figure}


\vfill

\begin{framed}
\footnotesize
Copyright. DOI. ISBN.
\lipsum[2-2]
\end{framed}

\end{document}
```

This looks like this:

[image]

## Aimed Output

[image]

Comment: No monkey patching, just use your own preamble, like described here: https://superuser.com/a/356044

Comment: Dear @keks-dose, I have my own template to replace default.latex. However, in both cases, pandoc replaces the $body$ tag with the rendered text, which contains images wrapped in a figure environment.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use the multicol package, no problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,DIV=22]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\title{MWE}
\author{Test Developer}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \lipsum[2-4]
\end{multicols}
\vfill

\fbox{%
\footnotesize
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.95\linewidth}
Copyright. DOI. ISBN.
\lipsum[2-2]
\end{minipage}
}

\end{document}
```

Cave: the package is named »multicol«, the environment »multicols«.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing this out. I just noticed that my figures are not supported any longer. While there are some work arounds with the caption package that avoid the figure environment, this is not an easy option in my case, as the figure environment is in the output of pandoc, which eventually will create my content.

I will update my MWE with the feedback so far.

Answer (score 1):

Hope the below tag may helps you:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{stfloats,framed}

\title{MWE}
\author{Test Developer}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{figure*}[b!]
\begin{framed}
Copyright. DOI. ISBN.
\lipsum[2-2]
\end{framed}
\end{figure*}

\lipsum[2-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank for pointing out stfloats. I didn't know it. It seems though this solution requires manual adjustment to place the box at the bottom of the last page. It works well when there is only one page. When I use `\lipsum[2-8]` and put the figure environment afterwards, it breaks.